# Question on Probability/ Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Seven guys each toss a die, independently from each other.

Answer the following questions and explain your solutions.

1) Calculate the probability that at least two of them will receive different outcomes.

2) Let $X$ be a random variable representing the maximum of all the outcomes, and let $Y$ stand for the minimum one. Calculate the joint probability, $PXY(5,4),$ that $X = 5$ AND $Y = 4.$

Use the tail sum formula to calculate the expected values of $X$ and $Y$:

3) Calculate the expected difference between the maximal and the minimal outcomes, $E(X - Y).$

I think that I am supposed to use a uniform distribution with this but I really cannot get this to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:*

1) $P(\text{At least two different})=1-P(\text{All the same})$

2) To have $X=5$ and $Y=4$, All outcomes, must be either $5$ or $4$. How ever we should omit two cases, all $4$, and all $5$.

3) Let's call the outcomes of dice rolls $D_1,D_2,...,D_7$

$P(Y  \ge a)= P(D_1 \ge a,D_2 \ge a,...,D_7 \ge a)=P(D_1 \ge a)P(D_2 \ge a)...P(D_7 \ge a)$

$P(X  \ge a)= P(\text{At least one of $D_i$s is greater than or equal to a}) \\=1-P(\text{All of $D_i$s are less than a})\\= 1-P(D_1 < a,D_2 < a,...,D_7 < a)=1-P(D_1 < a)P(D_2 < a)...P(D_7 < a)$

Note that $E[X-Y]=E[X]-E[Y]$

Comment: For 1) I got the answer46655/46656, and for 2) I got 7/15552. Are these correct or are they along the right line? With 3) what does the a stand for and where does the Expectation values come from?

Comment: @user114932 I don't have the exact numbers right now For 1) The answer is $1-7*(\frac{1}{6})^7$. For 2) The answer is $(\frac{2}{6})^7-2(\frac{1}{6})^7$ For 3) Search for "the tail sum formula to calculate the expected value"

Comment: I can't seem to find any good information on the tail sum formula or how to use it. Do you know of any good loctions in which I could find this information?